# Orion v2 registrations are not working in server:port/v2/registrations

Tags: fiware-orion

when I make a GET operation on my local Orion ContextBroker(I tried also at the fiware-lab one[orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026]) on this url http://10.174.123.243:1026/v2/ or it works fine and show me the allowed operations by ORION:

```
{
    "entities_url": "/v2/entities",
    "types_url": "/v2/types",
    "subscriptions_url": "/v2/subscriptions",
    "registrations_url": "/v2/registrations"
}
```

All of them are working except the /v2/registrations one. When I tried the following GET operation http://10.174.123.243:1026/v2/registrations I get a 400 error.

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "service not found"
}
```

Is not avaliable the `GET /v2/registrations` operation at Orion Context Broker? I've tried with Orion 0.24 and 1.2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registrations management has not been yet defined in NGSIv2. Although the [work-in-progress version of the NGSIv2 specification](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/latest) shows some "draft operations" related with registrations (as the one you mention) and it is something that in some moment will be defined, Orion is not implementing them by the time being (i.e. Orion version 1.2).

Note that [the current (May 2016) NGSIv2 specification release candidate](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable) doesn't include that operation.

However, Orion still supports NGSIv1 registration management (have a look to the [Orion NGSIv1 walkthrough](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#context-availability-management-using-ngsi9)).

Comment: NGSIv2 May 2016 release candidate is not yet available at http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable, but it will be by June 8th.

Comment: In all cases, if you ask the services avaliable with the url http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/v2 the answer continues including the v2/registrations operation in the response.

Comment: That's correct, in order to prepare the `GET /v2` operation for the future implementation of registrations management.

Comment: Ok. Fine. Thanks for the answers. Another related question. We are using v2 operations to retrieve info. If we register any context provider using v1 operation, will that context provider  work under any v2 operation like GET v2/entities? In afirmative case, what is the expected forwarding behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order not mixing old and new questions, could you ask that new question on an now post at StackOverflow, please? Thanks!